# error while sending saml request

Tags: java, saml, adfs

In our scnario we want to configure our java project with saml sso and for that we are using ADFS 3.0 and SAML 2.0

Web Server Glashfish 3.1.2 Java Version 7 and in the index.jsp file we have entered below entries.

```
//this is were we want to redirect the page after login i.e on our project
setAssertionConsumerServiceUrl("http://localhost/xyz/");

//this is metadata url
setIssuer("https://signon.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml");

//this is login page url
setIdpSsoTargetUrl("https://signon.example.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon");
```

I am getting this error on adfs server
I am sending saml request , able to open login page but after login it goes to error page, where after login i want to redirect it to my application.

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name: 
Saml

Relying Party: 
https://signon.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Exception details:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = Microsoft.IdentityServer.Tokens.MSISSecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ResolveSigningCredentials()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadAuthnRequest(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadSamlMessage(XmlReader reader, NamespaceContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String encodedSamlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Comment: That's not the address of the RP, it's the address of the metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Please describe a bit more I am new to this.

now we are getting below error, after sending unsigned request.
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Policy.PolicyServer.Engine.AssertionConsumerServiceUrlDoesNotMatchPolicyException: MSIS3200: 
No AssertionConsumerService is configured on the relying party trust 'https://signon.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml' 
that is a prefix match of the AssertionConsumerService URL 'http://localhost/java-saml/consume.jsp'
 specified by the request.

Comment: You need to add an RP endpoint which is the endpoint where your app can get and decode the SAML token.

Comment: This is in the ADFS wizard.

Comment: can you please help me in adding RP endpoint. I am not able to figure it out